# apache_request_headers and array_key_exists

Tags: php, android, http-headers

This is more of a warning than of a question, but someone may be able to provide a better solution.

I am sending a custom request header from my Android application.
When the request arrives on the PHP server, I check for the existence of this header and its values.
To do this, I get the header array with **`apache_request_headers()`** and then do a check for the header with **`array_key_exists()`**.

However, **`array_key_exists('custom-header', $Hdr)`** will return **false** !
So I dump the array with print_r and, lo and behold, the array key does exist in the array.
Here is the output :

```
Array
(
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip
    [Connection] => Keep-Alive
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [Content-Length] => 103
    [Host] => www.somedomain.com
    [custom-header] => my-custom-header-value
)
```

How did I get around this ?

Clone the array like this :

```
// recuperate the request headers
$Hdr = apache_request_headers();

// clone the array as it will not correctly search with array_key_exists
$Keys = array_keys($Hdr);
$Values = array_values($Hdr);
$Headers = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($Keys); $i++)
{
    $Headers[$Keys[$i]] = $Values[$i];
}
```

Now when I query the new array with **`array_key_exists('custom-header', $Headers)`**, it returns true !

Is this a known problem ?

Is there a better solution ?

**NOTE** : *I have changed the names of the real values to protect my code, this is given here as an example - please do not post corrections to these values* :-)

**EDIT** : This occurs on my shared server running PHP version 5.3.10 on Apache version 2.2.22

Comment: Will `isset($Hdr["Custom-header"])` return true?

Comment: can you actually provide the code where you have the issue? it doesn't make sense that for some array it doesn't work but when you copy the stuff to an identical array, it works. At least, I would like to see a concrete test case showing the behaviour.

Comment: @Passerby - no this did not work either.

Comment: @eis - the concrete code is simply that which I described.  I cannot provide the code from my Android application.  I totally agree that it does not make sense.  Note again : this occurs when an external application makes a request to the PHP server.  So a real life example would need to be coded for testing.  If you are an Android developer as well, I am sure you would be able to put this together.

Comment: Concrete code or it didn't happen. It's simply not believable without a verifiable example that can be duplicated. It's very difficult to accept your explanation that PHP's stock datastructure "doesn't work."

Comment: Also there is `array_combine(keys, values)` so you can spare the foreach. Also check if the two arrays are identical or not like `$Hdr === $Headers`. Additionally provide the raw HTTP request and add it to your question otherwise as @rdlowrey wrote, it's not contructive how you ask that question.

Comment: @Simon the issue does not sound like to be really related to android - it sounds like an HTTP request which can be easily duplicated and sent with, for example, curl or netcat. You can record the HTTP request and resend it if needs be. That would give a reproducable test case to work with. Although, if you have the stuff in an array, the behaviour should be reproducable even without http traffic.

Comment: @rdlowrey http://androidgmap.letrajet.com/ easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

Following your code example:

```
$Hdr = apache_request_headers();

$Keys = array_keys($Hdr);
$Values = array_values($Hdr);
$Headers = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($Keys); $i++)
{
    $Headers[$Keys[$i]] = $Values[$i];
}

var_dump($Hdr === $Headers); # true
```

We can conclude that `$Hdr` is equal to `$Headers`. <sub>(why wouldn't it be)</sub>

You should know that `array_key_exists` is case sensitive, therefore `Custom-Header` and `custom-header` are not the same keys.

Could you perchance try:

```
array_key_exists('custom-header', array_change_key_case($Hdr));
```

Or change your code a bit:

```
$Hdr = apache_request_headers();
$Headers = array();
foreach($Hdr as $Key => $Value)
{
    $Headers[strtolower($Key)] = $Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your example data

```
Array
(
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip
    [Connection] => Keep-Alive
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [Content-Length] => 104
    [Host] => androidgmap.letrajet.com
    [User-Agent] => LeTrajet Edition Cèdre
    [letrajet-sig] => 32dbc2........
)
```

this contains two possible issues, a lower case header name and "è" character, which might or might not be encoded properly in your request and/or comparison code. More details would be needed to verify, but this:

```
key is missing : false
MyUserAgent == 'LeTrajet Edition CÃ¨dre' : false
```

raises a suspicion that you have a character set issue with "è" character. You'd need to fix that in your PHP code doing the comparison. However, this issue is with data, not with header key.

You have this in your code, too:

```
else if($MyUserAgent == "LeTrajet Edition Cedre"
```

How can that match if in your data you have Cèdre?

Edit: truncated the signature as per comments from OP.

Comment: Where on earth did you get this from ?  It is not at all the data that I posted !

Comment: It's from the data user rlemon posted in the comments, as a response to asking for the code. See the question comments. If that's not correct data/source code, please let us now and preferrably supply the correct ones.

Comment: I see that you decided to go and take my code from my server, even though I stated that I wanted to protect my code.  Please delete the data you have copied here without my permission !

Comment: @Simon um, if you want to protect your code, you probably shouldn't post it to Internet, right? I can edit it out here, but that doesn't remove it being available for everyone, and it doesn't help resolving the issue.

Comment: @Simon this isn't code, it is header requests which are public info. Not to mention your url is forever stored on SO now in the revisions. You should parse out any unwanted data before asking a question.

Comment: Honestly I don't know why you edited the answer, I can see the full header by clicking on the revisions...

Comment: @Bot as per OP request. Doesn't make a lot of sense to me either, but don't really care, and truncating the signature doesn't change the problem.